# PyTorch flatten doesn't maintain batch size

Tags: python, pytorch

In Keras, using the `Flatten()` layer retains the batch size. For eg, if the input shape to Flatten is `(32, 100, 100)`, in `Keras` output of Flatten is `(32, 10000)`, but in PyTorch it is `320000`. Why is it so?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As OP already pointed out in their answer, the tensor operations do not default to considering a batch dimension. You can use [`torch.flatten()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.flatten) or [`Tensor.flatten()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.flatten) with `start_dim=1` to start the flattening operation after the batch dimension.

Alternatively since PyTorch 1.2.0 you can define an [`nn.Flatten()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html?highlight=flatten#torch.nn.Flatten) layer in your model which defaults to `start_dim=1`.

Comment: I tried both methods when training a GNN, but I seem to be missing something. In my `DataLoader` object, `batch_size` is mixed with the first dimension of input (in my GNN, the input unpacked from `DataLoader` object is of size `[batch_size*node_num, attribute_num]`), so if I use `torch.flatten()`, samples are mixed together and there would be only 1 output from this network, while I expect #`batch_size` outputs. And if I use `nn.Flatten()`, nothing seems to happen and the output of this layer is still `[batch_size*node_num, attribute_num]`.  How can I deal with this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, As mentioned in [this thread](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/do-i-need-to-consider-the-batch-size-when-defining-own-module/16292/2), PyTorch operations such as Flatten, view, reshape.

In general when using modules like `Conv2d`, you don't need to worry about batch size. PyTorch takes care of it. But when dealing directly with tensors, you need to take care of batch size.

In Keras, `Flatten()` is a layer. But in PyTorch, `flatten()` is an operation on the tensor. Hence, batch size needs to be taken care manually.