# How to implement Flatten layer with batch size > 1 in Pytorch (Pytorch_Geometric)

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network, flatten

I am new to Pytorch and am trying to transfer my previous code from Tensorflow to Pytorch due to memory issues.  However, when trying to reproduce `Flatten` layer, some issues kept coming out.

In my `DataLoader` object, `batch_size` is mixed with the first dimension of input (in my GNN, the input unpacked from `DataLoader` object is of size [batch_size*node_num, attribute_num], e.g. [4*896, 32] after the GCNConv layers). Basically, if I implement `torch.flatten()` after `GCNConv`, samples are mixed together (to [4*896*32]) and there would be only 1 output from this network, while I expect #batch_size outputs. And if I use `nn.Flatten()` instead, nothing seems to happen (still [4*896, 32]).  Should I set batch_size as the first dim of the input at the very beginning, or should I directly use `view()` function?  I tried directly using `view()` and it (seemed to have) worked, although I am not sure if this is the same as Flatten.  Please refer to my code below.  I am currently using global_max_pool because it works (it can separate `batch_size` directly).

By the way, I am not sure why training is so slow in Pytorch...  When `node_num` is raised to 13000, I need an hour to go through an epoch, and I have 100 epoch per test fold and 10 test folds.  In tensorflow the whole training process only takes several hours.  Same network architecture and raw input data, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67178061/how-to-solve-oom-when-allocating-tensor-with-shapexxx-in-tensorflow-when-tr) in another post of mine, which also described the memory issues I met when using TF.

Have been quite frustrated for a while.  I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60115633/pytorch-flatten-doesnt-maintain-batch-size) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45584907/flatten-layer-of-pytorch-build-by-sequential-container) post, but it seems their problems somewhat differ from mine.  Would greatly appreciate any help!

Code:

```py
# Generate dataset
class STDataset(InMemoryDataset):
    def __init__(self, root, transform=None, pre_transform=None):
        super(STDataset, self).__init__(root, transform, pre_transform)
        self.data, self.slices = torch.load(self.processed_paths[0])
    
    @property
    def raw_file_names(self):
        return []

    @property
    def processed_file_names(self):
        return ['pygdata.pt']

    def download(self):
        pass

    def process(self):
        data_list= []
        for i in range(sample_size):
            data = Data(x=torch.tensor(X_all[i],dtype=torch.float),edge_index=edge_index,y=torch.FloatTensor(y_all[i]))
            data_list.append(data)

        data, slices = self.collate(data_list)
        torch.save((data, slices), self.processed_paths[0])
        
dataset = STDataset(root=save_dir)
train_dataset = dataset[:len(X_train)]
val_dataset = dataset[len(X_train):(len(X_train)+len(X_val))]
test_dataset = dataset[(len(X_train)+len(X_val)):]


# Build network

from torch_geometric.nn import GCNConv, GATConv, TopKPooling, global_max_pool, global_mean_pool
from torch.nn import Flatten, Linear, ELU
import torch.nn.functional as F

class GCN(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(GCN, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = GCNConv(in_channels = feature_num, out_channels = 32)
        self.conv2 = GCNConv(in_channels = 32, out_channels = 32)
        self.fc1 = Flatten()
#         self.ln1 = Linear(in_features = batch_size*N*32, out_features = 512) 
        self.ln1 = Linear(in_features = 32, out_features = 32)
        self.ln2 = Linear(in_features = 32, out_features = 1) 

    
    def forward(self,x,edge_index,batch):   
#         x, edge_index, batch = data.x, data.edge_index, data.batch
#         print(np.shape(x),np.shape(edge_index),np.shape(batch))
        x = F.elu(self.conv1(x,edge_index))
#         x = x.squeeze(1) 
        x = F.elu(self.conv2(x,edge_index))
        print(np.shape(x))
        x = self.fc1(x)
#         x = torch.flatten(x,0)
#         x = torch.cat([global_max_pool(x,batch),global_mean_pool(x,batch)],dim=1)
        print(np.shape(x))
        x = self.ln1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        ## Dropout?
        print("o")
        x = torch.sigmoid(self.ln2(x))
        return x
        
# training
def train():
    model.train()
    loss_all=0
    correct = 0
    for i, data in enumerate(train_loader, 0):
        data = data.to(device)
        optimizer.zero_grad() 
        output = model(data.x, data.edge_index,data.batch)
        label = data.y.to(device)
        loss = loss_func(output, label)
        loss.backward()
        loss_all += loss.item()
        
        output = output.detach().cpu().numpy().squeeze()
        label = label.detach().cpu().numpy().squeeze()        
        correct += (abs(output-label)<0.5).sum()
        
        optimizer.step()
  
    return loss_all / len(train_dataset), correct / len(train_dataset)

device = torch.device('cuda')
model = GCN().to(device)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
loss_func = torch.nn.BCELoss()  # binary cross-entropy
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle = True)
val_loader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle = True)
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    gc.collect()
    train_loss, train_acc = train()
```

Error message for using `torch.nn.Flatten(start_dim = 1)` (code above):

```py
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-c96e8b058742> in <module>
     65 for epoch in range(num_epochs):
     66     gc.collect()
---> 67     train_loss, train_acc = train()

<ipython-input-42-c96e8b058742> in train()
     10         output = model(data.x, data.edge_index,data.batch)
     11         label = data.y.to(device)
---> 12         loss = loss_func(output, label)
     13         loss.backward()
     14         loss_all += loss.item()

~/miniconda3/envs/ST-Torch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    530             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    531         else:
--> 532             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    533         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    534             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

~/miniconda3/envs/ST-Torch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/loss.py in forward(self, input, target)
    496 
    497     def forward(self, input, target):
--> 498         return F.binary_cross_entropy(input, target, weight=self.weight, reduction=self.reduction)
    499 
    500 

~/miniconda3/envs/ST-Torch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in binary_cross_entropy(input, target, weight, size_average, reduce, reduction)
   2068     if input.numel() != target.numel():
   2069         raise ValueError("Target and input must have the same number of elements. target nelement ({}) "
-> 2070                          "!= input nelement ({})".format(target.numel(), input.numel()))
   2071 
   2072     if weight is not None:

ValueError: Target and input must have the same number of elements. target nelement (4) != input nelement (3584)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you want the shape to be `batch_size*node_num, attribute_num` is kinda weird.

Usually it should be `batch_size, node_num*attribute_num` as you need to match the input to the output. And `Flatten` in Pytorch does exactly that.

If what you want is really `batch_size*node_num, attribute_num` then you left with only reshaping the tensor using `view` or `reshape`. And actually Flatten itself just calls `.reshape`.

> `tensor.view`: This will reshape the existing tensor to a new shape, if you edit this new tensor the old one will change too.

> `tensor.reshape`: This will create a new tensor using the data from old tensor but with new shape.

```
    def forward(self,x,edge_index,batch):   
        x = F.elu(self.conv1(x,edge_index))
        x = F.elu(self.conv2(x,edge_index))

        # print(np.shape(x)) # don't use this
        print(x.size())  # use this

        # x = self.fc1(x)  # this is the old one
        ## choose one of these
        x = x.view(4*896, 32)
        x = x.reshape(4*896, 32)  

        # print(np.shape(x)) # don't use this
        print(x.size())  # use this

        x = self.ln1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        ## Dropout?
        print("o")
        x = torch.sigmoid(self.ln2(x))
        return x
```

## Edit 2 reshape

Let's say we have an array of `[[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]]]` which shape `(1, 2, 3)`, which represent `(batch, length, channel)` in Tensorflow.

If you want to use this data properly in Pytorch you need to make it `(batch, channel, length)`, which is `(1, 3, 2)`.

Here's the difference between `permute` and `reshape`

```
>>> x = torch.tensor([[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]]])
>>> x.size()
torch.Size([1, 2, 3])
>>> x[0, 0, :]
tensor([1, 1, 1])
>>> y = x.reshape((1, 3, 2))
>>> y
tensor([[[1, 1],
         [1, 2],
         [2, 2]]])
>>> y[0, :, 0]
tensor([1, 1, 2])
>>> z = x.permute(0, 2, 1)
>>> z
tensor([[[1, 2],
         [1, 2],
         [1, 2]]])
>>> z[0, :, 0]
tensor([1, 1, 1])
```

As you can see, the first channel of both `x` and `z` are `[1, 1, 1]` which is what we want while `y` is `[1, 1, 2]`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations!  Helps a lot.  I actually want `[batch_size, node_num, attribute_num]` as it would be encoded in Tensorflow, but the `DataLoader()` function (used as tutorials taught) just gives me `[batch_size*node_num, attribute_num]`.  I thought it was normal Pytorch logic, but looks like it's not?  I do hope it could be something else honestly ;)   Maybe I should manually reshape the input at the very beginning of the network?

Comment: @jasperhyp Pytorch is actually work similar to Tensorflow. You just need to swap the channel axis from the last channel to right after the batch.

Comment: If the code in tutorials work then it's fine. But otherwise you can also use Tensorflow's data loader and change the channel then convert to torch tensor.

Comment: Thanks for your comment!  I am not sure if I understand "swap the channel axis from the last channel to right after the batch".  Do you mean reshape the input data directly?  I now think not having `batch_size` as an independent dimension is truly problematic, because any layers related to batch (e.g. batch normalization layers) are not working as expected.

Comment: Not reshape but `permute`. For numpy array it called `rollaxis` or `swapaxis`.

Comment: @jasperhyp I explained a little bit more about that in edit2

Comment: Thanks for your examples!  I understand that now.  Looks like the revised code is working properly now, though still quite slowly ;)